# Shall I replace strut?

Tags: toyota, camry, leak, struts

2002 Camry LE, 150,000 miles. The rear passenger side leaks, but the rear driver side seems okay. They have been like these for 3 or more years. The riding experence has been okay, not bumpy.  If I want to keep the car for 5 more years, shall I replace both of them?

Rear passenger side
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Rear driver side
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a word: **Yes** you should change this.

Not only is the bellows toast, the juice running down the sides of the strut came from the strut. This guy is toast. If you're going to change this, change both sides so it's equal.

Comment: If I want to keep the car for 5 more years, shall I replace both of them?

Comment: @bobby_yan - You should place them both, anyways.

Comment: The failure mode is that the rebound on the leaking side is uncontrolled. You hit a bump in the road on a bend, you are momentarily driving a three-wheeled car, and it spins out because the other rear tyre does not have enough loading to grip. In the UK, this would fail the annual MOT safety test.

Comment: **Urgent note**: If you are intending to replace these yourself and you're buying individual parts and not preassembled units, please, please, please spend the money on a decent set of coil spring compressors. There is a frightening amount of stored energy in the coilover spring assembly and it can cause serious injury if not properly managed. With proper tools this is a manageable DIY job (I've done it on a 2011 Mini Cooper) but do not cheap out on, or otherwise "internet hack", the compression of the springs.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I think I would buy the assemblies anyway.

Comment: Replacing pre-built assemblies is a piece of cake, @bobby_yan. If you'd like to replace just the struts, most US auto parts stores have free loaner tools - you buy the spring compressors, use them, then return them for a full refund. (If you don't return them, well, you already bought them...) Also, make sure you've got a good torque wrench and _properly_ torque all mounting bolts. _Over_ torquing is just as bad as under torquing, and if any of the mounts fail, you could cause yourself a serious accident.